# Should points in geometry be italic?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

Variables should be italic, that's where we all agree (I think). So, a length of a segment could be marked with *a*. What about using |AB| for length of line segment? What about notation for a triangle? Should it be *ABC* or ABC?

Comment: They are not variables but the labels for the points; if angle ABC is a right angle you can't vary the points and still have right angles. Hence in my humble opinion they should e upright. But this is not on-topic here I'm afraid as it is a choce question.

Comment: All standards are a kind of "choice". I believe this is still on-topic, since it's about proper (standardized) usage of LaTeX. Of course, if people disagree (and this question gets closed), I'd understand.

Comment: That's just a stylistic decision. Be coherent in the document.

Comment: Well your question is not about TeX or that stuff is an orthotypograpical doubt. The answer shoudl be NO. Why? Because the non alphabetic signs such dots, bars, etc. have another usage.

You don't need the punctuation and alphabetic signs fit or combine with italics or bolds, however many font families include brackets and some punctuation such as periods, commas and parentheses.